# Let $S_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-i) \left ( 1 +\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n-i} \right )}$. Does $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

We define a sequence $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ by
$$
S_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-i) \left ( 1 +\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n-i} \right )}.
$$

Clearly, $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ does not have a form of a series, so I could not use [convergence tests](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_tests). Numerical computation shows that
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrr|}
            n   & 10 & 10^2 & 10^3 & 10^4 & 10^5 & 10^6  & 10^7 \\ \hline
           S_n &   1.965 &  2.533 &  2.900 &   3.168 &   3.380 & 3.554 &3.702
\end{array}
$$

Could you elaborate on the convergence of $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$S_n\asymp1+\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{1}{j\ln j}>1+\int_{2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx=1+\ln\ln(n+1)-\ln\ln2\to\infty$$

Answer (score 6):

First, re-index to write
$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{kH_k}$$
where $H_k = 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1k$.

Then since $H_k \sim \ln k$ and each term in $S_n$ is non-negative, $S_n$ will converge if and only if $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k\ln k}$ does.

This diverges, for instance by the integral test.

Answer (score 1):

This type of of series is of the form
$$\sum_n\frac{a_n}{s_n}$$
where $s_0=0$ and $s_n=\sum^n_{k=1}a_k$. There is a general result that states

> Prop: If $a_n\geq0$, and $\sum_na_n=\infty$, then $\sum_n\frac{a_n}{s_n}=\infty$.

In the OP'scase $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_n\frac{1}{n}=\infty$.

---

Here is a proof the Proposition stated above.

Observe that
$$\sum_n\frac{a_n}{s_n}=\sum_n\big(1-\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}\big)$$
If $\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}$ does not converge to $1$, the statement follows trivially.

Assume that $\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$. Then,for some $N$ large enough
$$\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}\geq\frac12\qquad\text{whenever}\quad n\geq N$$
Now we use a well known Calculus inequality
$$\frac{t}{1+t}\leq \log(1+t)\leq t\qquad\text{whenever}\quad1+t>0$$
to obtain (with $1+t=\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}$)
$$1-\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}\leq -\log\big(\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}\big)\leq 2\big(1-\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_n}\big)\qquad n\geq N$$
Since $\sum^N_{n=2}\log(s_{n-1}/s_n)=\log(s_n)-\log(s_1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$, the divergence of $\sum_n\frac{a_n}{s_n}$ follows.